# Rails3 UJS Tutorial for a guy somewhat experienced in Rails3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ujs

I am just wondering if there are any Rails 3 books that can help with Rails3 UJS understanding it etc, along with beginner rails3 chapters? Even if there is a book only about Rails3 UJS, that would be awesome too

Comment: Just read source code, it's really not so hard... no books out there for the UJS specifically for the Rails3 jQuery/Prototype implementations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is all on the web.
Check these links:

http://www.railsinside.com/tips/451-howto-unobtrusive-javascript-with-rails-3.html
 http://blog.jordanwest.me/modest-rubyist-archive/rails-3-ujs-and-csrf-meta-tags

You can also check the Rails 3 Way book on Amazon.

Comment: The second link is dead and the first one is about installing it.

Comment: @spartacus Link fixed. Thanks.